# Mittag Leffler partial fraction expansion for $\frac{\sin(z)}{\sin(\pi z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-fractions

I want to prove the following identity:
$$\dfrac{\sin(z)}{\sin(\pi z)} = \dfrac{1}{\pi} + \dfrac{z}{\pi}\sum_{n \neq 0}(-1)^n \dfrac{\sin(n)}{n(z-n)} $$

using Mittag-Leffler. 
I'm able to show that we have 
$$\dfrac{\sin(z)}{\sin(\pi z)} = \dfrac{z}{\pi}\sum_{n \neq 0}(-1)^n \dfrac{\sin(n)}{n(z-n)} +g(z)$$
 whee $g(z)$ is entire, so the goal would be to show that $g$ is bounded, hence constant. I don't see any periodicity conditions here that would help me.

what kind of observations should I make here?

Comment: [$\underline{\mathrm{Mittag-Leffler\ Expansion}}$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.10.E25).

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Simple poles of $\ds{\sin\pars{z}/\sin\pars{\pi z}}$ are at
>   $\ds{n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\braces{0}}$ with correspondent residues
>   $\ds{r_{n} = \lim_{z \to n}\bracks{\pars{z - n}\sin\pars{z}/\sin\pars{\pi z}} =
> \pars{-1}^{n}\,\sin\pars{n}/\pi}$. Moreover,
>   $\ds{\sum_{{\large n = -\infty} \atop {\large n \not= 0}}^{\infty}{r_{n}/n^{2}}}$ is *convergent*

such that its [Mittag-Leffler Expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.10.E25) becomes
\begin{align}
{\sin\pars{z} \over \sin\pars{\pi z}} - {1 \over \pi} & =
\sum_{{\large n = -\infty} \atop {\large n \not= 0}}^{\infty}
r_{n}\pars{{1 \over z - n} + {1 \over n}}
\\[5mm]
{\sin\pars{z} \over \sin\pars{\pi z}} & =
{1 \over \pi} + {1 \over \pi}
\sum_{{\large n = -\infty} \atop {\large n \not= 0}}^{\infty}
\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\sin\pars{n} \over z - n}\ +\
\underbrace{{1 \over \pi}\sum_{{\large n = -\infty} \atop {\large n \not= 0}}^{\infty}
\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\mrm{sinc}\pars{n}}}_{\ds{\equiv \,\mrm{g}\pars{z} = \color{red}{\large 0}}}
\end{align}

Comment: is the "$\text{sinc}(n)$ a typo?

Comment: @LuigiM No. $\displaystyle\mathrm{sinc}\left(x\right) = {\sin\left(x\right) \over x}$ when $\displaystyle x \not= \color{red}{0}$ and $\displaystyle\color{red}{1}$ otherwise. See [$\underline{\mathrm{this\ link}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).

Comment: Dear Felix, sorry for late commenting. (I'm trying to understand the steps) How did you justify the last passage, i.e. splitting the sum in the two sum since the first one is not absolute convergent? It's the first time I've seen such a trick, so I'd like understanding it more

Answer (score 1):

Look at the limits as $\Im(z) \to \pm \infty$. Since $\pi>1$, the left-hand side tends to zero. If you can show that the sum on the right-hand side is bounded as $\Im(z) \to \pm \infty$, then $g$ is entire and bounded away from the real line, so must be constant.

Comment: How did you observe that $g$ is periodic?

Comment: Hang on, it's not obvious that it's periodic, is it. Indeed, the left-hand side isn't. But showing the difference is bounded will be sufficient.

Comment: which is where I've problems. in the imaginary direction things go as you say, but what happen in the "real direction"?

Comment: Yes, this is rather more difficult than I first thought. You can show that for $k$ a nonzero integer $\frac{\sin{z}}{\sin{\pi z}} - \frac{(-1)^k z\sin{k}}{\pi k(z-k)}$ is bounded above uniformly on $k-1/2<\Re z < k+1/2$ quite easily. It remains to bound the rest of the sum uniformly in $z$. It should be possible to write the series in such a way that the bounding is not especially difficult (one might try combining the positive and negative terms, for example), and then estimating to remove the awkward $(-1)^n\sin{n}$ by noting that it is $ \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

> $$f(z)= \dfrac{\sin(z)}{\sin(\pi z)} -\frac1\pi \lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{0<|n|\le N}(-1)^n \dfrac{\sin(n)}{z-n}=g(z)-h(z)$$ is entire.

Differentiating, $g'$ is bounded away from its poles, the series for $h'$
is uniformly convergent thus bounded away from its poles, and the boundedness of $f'$ on $|z-n|=1/2$ plus the Cauchy integral formula implies that $f'$ is bounded on $|z-n|<1/3$, thus constant.

Since $g'(i\infty)=h'(i\infty)=0$ it means that $f' = 0$.

Thus $f$ is constant ie. $$f = f(0) =\frac1\pi $$

The general Mittag-Leffler theorem is mostly the abstraction of this reasonning.